# Is there a better solution than this to print the results

Tags: php

```
<?php
$arr = 
[
'name' => 'hussin' ,
"age"  => 25,
'job' => 
[
'php', 'ajax'
]
];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
{
if(!is_array($arr[$key]))
echo $key .' '. $value."<br>";
else
foreach ($arr['job'] as $key => $value) 
echo $key .' '. $value."<br>";
}
?>
```

result 
name Hussien
age  27
0 php
1 ajax

Is there a better solution than this to print the results?
I have an associative array with regular data, including a array type, which is the best solution for accessing all data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but I think you're looking for a recursive algorithm:

```
function printAll(array $arr){
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            return printAll($v);
        }
        print $k . ":" . $v . "\r\n";
    }
}

printAll(['name' => 'hussin' ,"age"  => 25,'job' => ['php', 'ajax']]); // name:hussin age:25 0:php 1:ajax
```

Now, this can of course be improved to deal with other iterables and the nested array keys, but hopefully you get the jist.